# Updating the file contents of a Django FileField during upload results in I/O error

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to encrypt the contents of a file that is being uploaded. This is the relevant code snippet:

```
class AppFile(models.Model):
    app_file = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_to, validators=[validate_file_size])
    encrypted_data_key = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)

    def encrypt_file_with_data_key(self, data_key):
        cipher = Fernet(data_key)
        with self.app_file.open(mode='rb') as file:
            file_data = file.read()
            encrypted_data = cipher.encrypt(file_data)
        with self.app_file.open(mode='wb') as encrypted_file:
            encrypted_file.write(encrypted_data)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self._state.adding is True:

            # New image being uploaded
            encrypted_data_key, data_key = self.generate_data_key_from_vault()
            self.encrypted_data_key = encrypted_data_key

            # Encrypt the uploaded image file
            self.encrypt_file_with_data_key(data_key)

        super().save(args, kwargs)
```

I prefer this approach as this is agnostic of the StorageProvider being used. I also want to avoid detaching the file to a temporary folder, and re-attach it after encryption.

However, this results in the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jeroenjacobs/.pyenv/versions/myapp/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/jeroenjacobs/.pyenv/versions/myapp/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/jeroenjacobs/.pyenv/versions/myapp/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 84, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/jeroenjacobs/.pyenv/versions/myapp/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 119, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/jeroenjacobs/.pyenv/versions/myapp/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 184, in post
    return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/jeroenjacobs/.pyenv/versions/myapp/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 153, in post
    return self.form_valid(form)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/jeroenjacobs/.pyenv/versions/myapp/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/contrib/messages/views.py", line 12, in form_valid
    response = super().form_valid(form)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/jeroenjacobs/.pyenv/versions/myapp/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 135, in form_valid
    self.object = form.save()
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/jeroenjacobs/.pyenv/versions/myapp/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 548, in save
    self.instance.save()
  File "/Users/jeroenjacobs/PycharmProjects/myapp/mainapp/models.py", line 90, in save
    self.encrypt_file_with_data_key(data_key)
  File "/Users/jeroenjacobs/PycharmProjects/myapp/mainapp/models.py", line 77, in encrypt_file_with_data_key
    with self.app_file.open(mode='wb') as encrypted_file:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/jeroenjacobs/.pyenv/versions/myapp/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py", line 80, in open
    self.file.open(mode)
  File "/Users/jeroenjacobs/.pyenv/versions/myapp/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/files/uploadedfile.py", line 115, in open
    self.file.seek(0)
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

Reading the contents doesn't seem to be a problem, but writing seems to generate an error, despite `open` being called.

Comment: I don't know what could be going on there. But that said, I am solving this exact issue right now on my own project by subclassing https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/files/storage/#django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage, and then customizing the `_open` and `_save` methods to include my encryption and decryption logic. Not sure if that approach could work for your situation though. Let me know if you'd like to see some code, I'd be glad to post an example.

Comment: @YellowShark The thing is, I want this to work independent of the storage provider, so subclassing  FileStorage is not really an option. I wonder if this is some kind of bug?

Comment: No opinion on the possibility of bug or not, but another idea just occurred to me: `app_file` is a file *field* - not an actual file. And that makes me wonder if maybe you need to reference the underlying `.file` property, like this: `self.app_file.file.open(mode='wb')`. I'd be curious to know if that changes anything!

Comment: @YellowShark I'll give this a try, but the read-part works just fine.